# ? Operator used in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I just started learning LINQ and then just stuck on an example statement provided in the tutorial (Please not that I am working with C# .Net Framework). The statement

```
 arr?.Count(w => w != null) > 0
```

returns `True` only if their is at-least one none-null element in the `arr` (array or list). But what is the `?` operator doing there? Is this another form or ternary operator or something else? Please share your precious knowledge on this point. I shall be glad and thankful to read good answers from you.

Note: I tried removing the `?` operator in the statement but could not find any difference.

Answer (score 2):

It's the [Null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

It's basically checking for null and executing the condition if not null.  In the case `arr` was null, this code would not throw an exception.  If written without the Null Conditional operator you would get a `NullReferenceException`.

```
// this would throw an exception
int?[] arr;
arr.Count(w => w != null) > 0;

// this will check if arr is null and not proceed to call the .Count method
int?[] arr;
arr?.Count(w => w != null) > 0;
```